# Trying to run a HTML5 accelerometer listener in the background on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, accelerometer, devicemotion

I'm currently in the process of creating a webapp that detects whether the user is sitting or standing. I have had great success with detecting the tilt of the device, changing a boolean variable and sending the correct data to a graph.

The following code runs perfectly in the background, updating the data every second.

```
var trackInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if(isSitting){
        addData(myPieChart, "Sitting");
    } else{
        addData(myPieChart, "Standing");
    }
}, 1000)
```

My issue is that the listening function that changes the variable 'isSitting' does not continue once the browser is closed. This means that the last value of 'isSitting' gets data added to it, even though the device might be tilted otherwise.

This is the code that creates the accelerometer updates:

```
window.addEventListener("devicemotion", accelerometerUpdate, true);

var isSitting = true;

function accelerometerUpdate(event) {
    var aX = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x * 100 ;
    var aY = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y * 100 ;
    var aZ = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z * 100 ;

    if (aY > 600 || aY < -900 ){
        isSitting = false;
    } else{
        isSitting = true;   
    }
}
```

I have tried Chrome, Opera and Firefox on my Android device.

Any help or tips to work around this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like regular behaviour as your javascript code, to be executed, should run in your browser.

To achieve your goal, a possible guess would be to look into a way to use this api in service workers, which is currently not possible with the devicemotion api but should be (at least with chrome) with the new Generic Sensors API described here : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sensors-for-the-web